# Is python package itself a module?

Tags: python, module, package, python-internals

I was just trying to understand modules and packages in python, and as fas as  I understood:

`A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.`

`A package is a directory containing modules or other packages.`

Now, I made a very simple directory structure like below:

```
my_package/
      __init__.py
      my_module.py
```

Then, inside the interpreter, I did:

```
>>> import my_package
>>> type(my_package)
<type 'module'>

>>> from my_package import my_module
>>> type(my_module)
<type 'module'>
```

So, Python says, my_package and my_module, both are modules. Where is the package? Is package just a term used for description purposes and has no official identity as a class or object inside the core language? What are packages and modules for the interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a package can be imported as a module; the module's contents are in `__init.py__`.

The term package refers to the directory; it allows modules and subpackages to exist in the package namespace.

Comment: So, it imports the package as a module. There is no term like package for a interpreter. Is it?

Comment: @ManishJain: the interpreter is aware of packages (e.g., it won't allow relative imports outside of them), but a package isn't a distinct object, no.